# Why am I getting this error: "remote end hung up unexpectedly"?

Tags: git

```
$ git push -u origin master   
Counting objects: 321523, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (85111/85111), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (321523/321523), 4.29 GiB | 17.11 MiB/s, done.
Total 321523 (delta 159406), reused 320112 (delta 158718)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 8):

Well, this is caused by some bad network status or some large files included in your commit.
In my case, I have tried after some mins, it worked.

So I suggest you should do push several times in some intervals, or
increase buffer size and then try to push again?

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 15728640
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this message when we converted a mercurial repository to git and tried to push it to GitHub. The cause turned out to be that we had previously committed some libraries' .git folders into our repository and folders with that name are [forbidden by git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498616/19696). The repository seemed to work fine locally and we even pushed it to CodeCommit successfully but GitHub is stricter about that rule and pushes to it would always fail with `error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053`

To see if that's your issue, you can run `git fsck` and look for instances of `The tree contains an entry with an invalid path of '.git'`

The solution for us was to use [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to get rid of the offending folders and we were then able to push to GitHub without issue.

```
$ bfg --delete-folders .git --delete-files .git  --no-blob-protection  my-repo.git
```

FYI, please thoroughly read the BFG information page before using it because it can create merging nightmares if used improperly.

Comment: It was not until I saw this and ran `git fsck` that I was able to determine that my repo had the .git folders...  


`warning in tree 3755606c52b3ad2ce499f9d314be29277e844695: hasDotgit: contains '.git'
warning in tree e869ae8178ee45ea3d7ca5b981dff905a600fd5c: hasDotgit: contains '.git'
warning in tree 0bb23c83789372df9352a44e2cd4f6cf3d306246: hasDotgit: contains '.git'
Checking objects: 100% (46997/46997), done.
`.    
   

I used `git filter-repo --path-glob '*/.git' --invert-paths --force` to remove them

Answer (score 3):

Posting the solution that worked for me...

**In Short**

Just change your network connection and then try again.

**The Story**

I was also getting this exception on command line (GIT Bash) as well as on [TortoiseGIT](https://tortoisegit.org/), when my laptop was connected to *Office WiFi*. Then I just disconnected my laptop from there and connected it to my *SmartPhone's HotSpot*. That's it, and error got resolved.

It could be weird for some techies, but no harm in try.

Answer (score 3):

After about 3 hours of trying, the problem was solved after using a **VPN**

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx) that errno 10053 is "Software caused connection to abort".

> An established connection was aborted by the software in your host computer, possibly due to a data transmission time-out or protocol error.

It looks like your server and/or network is unstable. Try to copy large amounts (> 1GB) of data using `scp` to isolate the problem.

Comment: I have this large depo which i want to host on github as a process of code migration from perforce to git. it goes well and at the end gives me this error. i don't know what to do

Comment: it has like 600 000 revisons

Comment: Can you successfully push it somwehere else, like a local SSH server?

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed similar issues for myself by increasing the memory and packsize limits:

```sh
git config --global pack.windowMemory 1048576000

git config --get pack.packSizeLimit 1048576000
```