# Push git repository to VSTS

Tags: git, azure-devops

I am converting repository from TFS to GIT, I am using git-tf tool. Currently I am at point where I have local repository and I am trying to push it on VSTS

I am using commands posted on VSTS:

```
git remote add origin https://app.visualstudio.com/MyProject/_git/MyRepo
git push -u origin --all
```

push output is as follow:

```
Counting objects: 1636, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1580/1580), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053
Writing objects: 100% (1636/1636), 1.34 GiB | 13.20 MiB/s, done.
Total 1636 (delta 1180), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unpack failed: error The tree object awert214681a38eae868f968d9f49dbc7236ba8e was rejected: The tree contains an entry with an invalid entry name of '.git'.
Everything up-to-date
```

not sure if first error

```
error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053
```

is responsible of second one

In the end repository was not pushed on VSTS and I am not sure how to fix it.

I was checking in repo browser and '.git' directory was not added to it. Also I have done some simple directories search and there is no other '.git' directory than one which is placed in root directory.

If anyone has any suggestions/ideas then I will appreciate those

Thanks for help

Comment: In this case, couldn't you run `git ls-tree -r 'awert21468' | grep '\.git$'` and see if it returns anything? (could be a conversion error)

Comment: There is such entry with '.git' directory, thanks

Comment: now just clean it up :)

Comment: You should be able to clean this up using the [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16842506 as well (essentially a duplicate of your question, shows how to clean this up using BFG)

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36410206/why-i-am-getting-this-error

Comment: What's the result if you try to push a new simple local repository to VSTS?

Comment: starain - I was not trying to push any new simple repository, I am guessing that there should not be any problem

Comment: Hasturkun - it looks like this question is duplicate, not sure how I have missed topic that you have mentioned