# POST git-receive-pack (chunked) fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, github, push

I am trying to push some files that amount to around 200mb to github. The largest file pushed is 2mb so it's just a lot of smallish files(images). I get this error on 2 different computers. One wireless and one wired.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks -c credential.helper= -c credential.helper="C:/Users/PCName/AppData/Local/ATLASS~1/SOURCE~1/GIT_EX~1/GIT-CR~1.EXE" push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to https://github.com/MyGitHubUsername/MyGitHubAddress.git
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

error: RPC failed; curl 55 SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 10053
Everything up-to-date
Completed with errors, see above.
```

I have tried the

```
git config http.postBuffer 100000000
```

command but still not working. My github space is this. But my repo size is quite large (< 20GB)

[image]

I have checked the related posts but the fixes don't seem to be working for me. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I assume you have already searched for everything `errno = 10053` https://stackoverflow.com/a/48157454/391691 and checked you did not add files with forbidden names

Comment: Are you using LFS ? Have you tried using a different network ?

Comment: Yes I have Git LFS and have tried at home and at work but they result in the same error.

Comment: I am assuming all your files (images) are being tracked by LFS, so the files were successfully pushed to LFS server and then you receive the error?

Comment: I only track really large images/files so I let the <2mb go through as normal. Nothing here is LFS.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following :

- Increase the `http.postBuffer` size to this `524288000` or maybe double `1048576000` as mentioned here [The remote end hung up unexpectedly while git cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6842687/10155936)
- Check the output of `git fsck` command, as a broken or a bad commit might cause errors too as mentioned here [link](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/3559)
- You can split your commit into several small commits and push them to remote. You could try this on a clone of your local repo. For example, instead of 10 images, commit 2 images at a time
- Probably as a last resort, switch to a LINUX machine or VM and check if the error still persists (updating git might also help)

Comment: I actually did solve this earlier with your third point. I made an empty repo and transferred all my files into it and pushed them all over 40 commits. It sucked but I have version control again so I'm happy. I have the broken one still so might try your suggestions just so I know for next time, Thanks

Comment: @ThomasByy, Any of the above points worked for the broken repo ?